# AWS Elastic Beanstalk - Custom Domain Problem with Route 53 hosted zone

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Hi i have laravel app deployed with AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

I have domain on cloudflare, I created hosted zone in AWS Route 53 with A record which is alias to my Elastic Beanstalk env but if i want to access app with this domain it just doesnt work, if i create A record with EC2 ip associated with Elastic Beanstalk env everything works, but when autoscaling pops up this ip changes, I tried to point DNS with CNAME to .elasticbeanstalk domain associated with app but same result, anyone had similar problem?

I tried using dig mydomain and answer section gives me 2 ip addresses - typing both to browser lets me access application, but neither of those two are same as ec2 intance associated with Elastic Beanstalk env,

I also tried using DNS Checker online, seems like some DNS servers reads my domain as those two IP addresses from dig command, some DNS servers reads my domain as a combination of EC2 instance address + one of address displayed in dig command

Any idea what can cause this? Server works on amazon linux + nginx on which i used certbot to get SSL Certificates (all 80 port requests are pointed to 443 port which seems working - because after typing http://domain I get 301 redirect to https://) nginx -t tells that configuration of nginx is ok

Answer (score 0):

The problem was lack of HTTPS listener in load balancer.

To resolve something like this:

- Go to configuration
- Find Load Balancer and Edit
- Add Listener for 443 Port HTTPS and SSL certificate